# How to pass value from modal dialog to parent page

Tags: asp.net, popup, modal-dialog

I am creating a website using asp.net. I am calling the modal dialog if the user click the login link.

This is my script for showModalDialog.

```
<li><a onclick="popup()"href="#">LOGIN</a></li>


 <script type="text/javascript">
 function popup() {
     var style = 'dialogWidth:350px;dialogHeight:100px;dialogleft:200px;dialogtop:200px;status:no;help:no;';
     var respond = window.showModalDialog("login.aspx", this, '', style);

 }
```

The login page consist of textbox for username and password and button for login button. After checking the username and password in the database my problem is how to pass the value from the popup page to parent page (boolean and string datatype) using code behind (.cs). If it is possible after passing the value to the parent page it will load the membership page if the boolean = true.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean that you want to pass var respond to cs?

Comment: No, I have a button in login page and I want all codes will be from .cs and the value will be passed to var respond.

Comment: I am sorry but i have difficulty to undestand what you want.

Comment: Can you get the result of dialog to your javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Could you expose the boolean in the code behind as a property which you can then write directly into the page i.e.

```
window.returnValue = '<%=MyPublicProperty%>;'
```

When the page is rendered then the property will just be any other javascript reference i.e.

```
window.returnValue = 'thePropertyValue';
```

So the modal dialog return type will reflect what was in the code behind

Another variation would be to use the `ClientScript` object to write the code behind variable into the markup so it is available to the client to return from the modal dialog

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "example", 
string.Format("var codeBehindProperty = '{0}';", MyPublicProperty), true);
```

Hope that makes sense

**EDIT**

And to retrieve that information it should be the return value from the showModalDialog call. So in your example

```
 var respond = window.showModalDialog("login.aspx", this, '', style);
```

The variable `respond` will contain the `codeBehindProperty`. If you were to step through the code then execution would pause at `showModalDialog` while the modal was opened. When it closes then the execution continues and the return value is then available in the parent page.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My problem now is after clicking the button the value will be passed to the parent page but how could I use it in my page (how to retrieve/catch the data)?